# A recurrence relation for the number of asterisks in the function

Tags: recurrence

I cannot get a recurrence for the number of asterisks printed by the function below, n is at least 2.

```
void Mystery(int n) {
   if (n >= 2) {
       print("**");
       n=n-1;
       Mystery(n);
       n=n-1
       Mystery(n);
       print("***");
   }
}
```

I have tried for n=2 case then I get **
Next, for n=3. Then for n=4. Then I tried to use induction method to get a general result for n. But I cannot reach any recurrence relation.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some points to think about:

- If n = 0 or n = 1, no asterisks are printed. Otherwise, exactly five asterisks are printed, plus those from the recursive calls.
- The first recursive call made is to Mystery(n - 1), and the second is to Mystery(n - 2).

Comment: So, a correct recurrence relation is T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) +5 ?

Comment: Yep, looks good! Just make sure to include proper base cases. :-)